# Copyrights on technical specifications

Tags: copyright, data

I'd like to list technical specs for electronic products on my site. I want to compile it from different sources (other sites, not manufacturers). Is it OK to do that? Tech specifications have not copyrights, right? I know that I should ask a permission, but my question is what consequences might be?
(Theoretically it is possible to find out that something was copied from particular source if errors are the same or the same set of parameters, ant so on)

Comment: The technical specification document is almost certainly copyrighted. A particular number in the document (e.g. 60 Hz) cannot be copyrighted.

Comment: @Brandin but what's about 'terms of use', like [link](https://www.imdb.com/conditions) or [link](https://www.gsmarena.com/terms.php3)? It is usually written that you may not copy ANY information from the website.

Comment: That could only apply to the copyrightable portions of the information. In particular, facts are not copyrightable. For example, according to IMDB, the movie Forrest Gump was released in 1994, is 142 minutes long, and stars Tom Hanks. IMDB does not "own" those three facts, even in the unlikely situation that no one else published those facts. However, if I copy an entire summary from IMDB, that is an expression and is copyrightable.